# css ie7 relative element appearing left and outside of containing element

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Continuing the ie7 debug. Thanks to previous posts I've discovered the tools in ie9 and their ability to help with debugging ie7 - brilliant - who'd have thought microsoft could develop a useful tool :)

ANyway...

Using a script from a tutorial I have a panel which slides in from the top and has a tab to click on to slide the panel open and close. The panel all works as expected apart from the tab which appears to the extreme left and partly outside it's containing element whereas it should line up to the right. The element is positioned relative to it's containing div and floats right.

The containing div appears where it should do on the page. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="tab">

<ul class="login">
 <li class="left">
  &nbsp; 
 </li>
 <li>
  Hello Guest! 
 </li>
 <li class="sep">
```

| 
     
     
      Log In |       Register Close Panel

```
</div>
```

and here's the CSS relating to the elements:

```
.tab {
background: url(../images/tab_b.png) repeat-x 0 0;
height: 42px;
position: relative;
top: 0;
z-index: 999;
}

.tab ul.login {
display: block;
position: relative;
float: right;
clear: right;
height: 42px;
width: auto;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 42px;
margin: 0;
right: 150px;
color: white;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
}

.tab ul.login li.left {
background: url(../images/tab_l.png) no-repeat left 0;
height: 42px;
width: 30px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display: block;
float: left;
}

.tab ul.login li.right {
background: url(../images/tab_r.png) no-repeat left 0;
height: 42px;
width: 30px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display: block;
float: left;
}

.tab ul.login li {
text-align: left;
padding: 0 6px;
display: block;
float: left;
height: 42px;
background: url(../images/tab_m.png) repeat-x 0 0;
}
```

What should I be looking out for with ie7 positioning bugs so I can try and hone in on the problem areas.

Thanks

Update: I tried a suggested answer below but no success yet. However I hadnt noticed that the parent wrappers are not correct. They are set to be width:100% but they start about 1/4 from the left of the page, as if they had a margin: HTML below:

```
   <DIV id=panel>
     <DIV class="content clearfix">
       <DIV class=left>
        CONTENT
       </DIV>
      <DIV class=left><!-- Login Form -->
      CONTENT
      </DIV>
      <DIV class="left right"><!-- Register Form -->
      CONTENT
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
    </DIV>
    <!-- /login -->
    <!-- The tab on top -->
    <DIV id=wrapper1>
      <DIV class=tab>
        <UL class=login>
           <LI class=left>&nbsp; </LI>
            <LI>Hello Guest! </LI>
            <LI class=sep>| </LI>
            <LI id=toggle>CONTENT</LI>
            <LI class=right>&nbsp; </LI>
       </UL>
     </DIV>
     </DIV>
```

The whole of the panel is off from the left whereas it should be across the entire page, the page infact needs to be scrolled to the right to see the whole element. This panel appears immediately after the  tag

The CSS for top panel etc:

```
   #toppanel {
   position: absolute;   /*Panel will overlap  content */
   /*position: relative;*/   /*Panel will "push" the content down */
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 999;
   text-align: center;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
  }

   #panel {
width: 100%;
height: 250px;
color: #999999;
background: #272727;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
display: none;
  }
```

Comment: Are you missing some markup? The last <li> isn't closed, nor is <ul>, and there are no elements with the 'right' class applied.

Comment: Hi, yes some missing from the paste I did - both are closed in the full page

Comment: exactly what is the problem and what you want?

Answer (score 1):

give your tab a `left:0px` and a wrapper.

IE 7 sets left:0px default and if you don't have another relative container around it, it's sets to the far left.

Comment: Hi I added the left:0px and added a wrapper div but no effect. I've edited my post with further info as I think the corruption occurs slightly higher up but I can't see why...

Comment: Can you add your code into http://jsfiddle.net/ and save it and post the link here?

Comment: Hi - something new again - never used that before. Here's the link, i've just pasted the html code relating to the elements involved and the css (extracted from ie developer toolkit) Hope it makes sense. It renders ok in jsfiddle minus the graphic backgrounds: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/longestdrive/r7vKt/0[/link]

Comment: I think some of it is inherited rather than items I've created - hold on I'll go in and remove to leave only the bits I've created...

Comment: just pasted the css from the file taht came with the script. Hope that makes better sense. I think the develop tool in ie must show every rule for the element (soz)

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/longestdrive/r7vKt/3/)[/link] - sorry - didnt realise it changed